# Playing video in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, media, silverlight-5.0

Im trying to play a video clip in my `Silverlight Application`.

```
        var video_path = "http://mydomain.com/path-to-media/file.wmv";
        mediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;

        mediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(video_path);
        mediaPlayer.Play();
        MessageBox.Show(mediaPlayer.Source.ToString()); //test the source string
```

But the video does not start or even display.

Is there a step I have forgotten ?

mediaPlayer is a simple Silverlight MediaElement

**Update**
When I attach a media Failed event and display the error exception i get

`4001 AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR`

Comment: Have a look in fiddler which request (if any) is actually made and whether it's served properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your silverlight application has a different URL scheme, and [cross-scheme access is not allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for media.

If the video URL starts from `http://`, your application URL should start from `http://` too.

I think your application URL looks something like `file:///C:/project/page.html`. If so, you should add a ASP.Net website to your solution and host your Silverlight application there so that your URL looks like `http://localhost:25252/page.html`.

Comment: Yes your right. I only just discovered that SL and its Domain restriction policy.